# GetCapabilities to themes.json

Tags: qgis, wms, getcapabilities, qwc2

We have the QWC2 client installed on our server and it opens correctly in the client with the standard Swiss layers.

We have a QGIS WMS Server running with a number of layers.

We want to know how to configure the themes.json so that it serves our layers.

The documentation says:

> themes.json - Full theme configuration, autogenerated from themesConfig.json

Creating themesConfig.json looks laborious given we have a large number of layers.

Is there any sort of utility that can generate a basic themesConfig.json from a GetCapabilities XML generated by the WMS server?